# How to send data to phase shift block in GNU Radio?

Tags: python, variables, signals, gnuradio, phase

I have a signal which is changing over time. This signal varies between -180 and 180, and is used to determine the phase shift using the "phase shift" block in GNU Radio.

[image: phase shift block]

[image: phase shift block parameters]

The phase shift can be manually determined by writing the desired phase shift value into the block:

[image: phase shift using a numeric value]

Alternatively, a variable can be used:

[image: phase shift using a variable]

I would like to use the signal which has been previously calculated to determine the phase shift. Is there a way to save it into a variable and then use it into the "phase shift" block?